# v-html en nuxt 3 no muestra contenido en su carga inicial

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt

estoy haciendo una consulta graphql en nuxt 3 y funciona bien, pero el contenido que necesito mostrar con v-html `(excerpt)` no se muestra en la carga inicial, al cambiar de sección y regresar ya lo muestra bien. Estoy usando nuxt/apollo para las consultas, el query lo tengo en un archivo .gql

```
query getPosts {
  posts {
    nodes {
      id
      date
      authorId
      title
      excerpt
}
```

El componente es el siguiente:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import getPosts from '~/queries/getPosts.gql'
    const { data:posts, pending, error, refresh } = await useLazyAsyncQuery( getPosts )   
</script>
<template>
    <div v-if="pending">
        <h1 class="text-">Cargando....</h1>
    </div>
    <div v-if="posts">
        <BlogCard 
            v-for="post in posts.posts.nodes"
            :key="post.id"
            :post="post"
        />
    </div>  
</template>
```

Este es el componente BlogCard,  aquí es donde deseo mostrar el campo `excerpt`, sin embargo no logro que se muestre en la carga inicial de la página:

```
<script setup>
    const props = defineProps({
        post:  {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    })
    const {id, title, excerpt } = props.post
</script>
<template>
    <div >
        <span >Design</span>
        <NuxtLink :to="{path:`blog/${id}`}">
            {{ title }} 
        </NuxtLink>
        <!-- AQUI VA EL CONTENIDO HTML - excerpt -->
        <p  v-html="excerpt"></p>
        <!-- AQUI VA EL CONTENIDO HTML - excerpt -->

        <div >
            <NuxtLink :to="{path:`blog/${id}`}">Ver más</NuxtLink>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

No logro conseguir que se muestre aunque verifico la data:posts  para mostrar el contenido.